# What is meant by DDBB?

Tags: terminology

Today we got a term `DDBB`. I am not sure whether it refer normal database or database driver in certain programming language.

Google search did not help me much in this. And I am sure it is not 'Dirty Dozen Brass Band'.

Comment: I've never seen it. It's probably either a typo or something proprietary.

Comment: Where did you hear this term? What was the context?

Comment: it is used in the context of huge databases

Comment: @ddaniel Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @AakashM As part of a project requirement. Client says he has DDBB.

Comment: @Junaid Ask the client what he means by DDBB

Comment: D to the D to the BBB!

Answer (score 12):

BBDD are Bases de Datos in this funny way in which Spanish refers to plural for acronyms (EEUU, Estados Unidos = United States). 
http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=390785

Comment: The best possible explanation I've seen yet.

Comment: I can confirm that. I have a spanish colloeage and just had the exact same conversation with him

Comment: I think user41118 is totally right; this is a "forced translation" from Spanish (usually we say "BBDD" regarding to more than one database).
I've read the other answer's source, and I'm afraid that the guy who posted this word is from Spain.... About the "funny way" of creating plural acronyms in Spanish... I have to say "it is what it is"... it's like the answer for "Thank you" in English... "Your welcome" it just doesn't make any sense, but like I said, it is what it is...

Answer (score 1):

from what I know, `DDBB` is just a "slang" word for `DB` (database) - nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: I understand the criticism, but I think @ddaniel is correct.  I had never seen this term before, but in searching on it, everywhere it shows up in the context of databases, it seems to be used as synonym for DDBB.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603215/600-tables-in-ddbb

Comment: That is, it seems to be used as synonym for "database":
http://bit.ly/1mlbSYJ
http://bit.ly/1sIaNwd
http://bit.ly/1oo62Z1
http://bit.ly/1gyUmuI

One commonality is that those using the term do not seem to be native English speakers, so perhaps DDBB is used in one or more other languages.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY... as from the previous answer I understood nothing... no spanish.. and not the word database/db in there. Upvoted this answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

DDBB is a way to refer to Bases de Datos (Data Bases), in Spanish plurals of nouns that are composed by two words are abbreviated duplicating the first letter of the word. e.g: EEUU - Estados Unidos, RRHH - Recursos Humanos, AAVV - Asociacion